# Handling non-numeric argument to binary operator error in ShinyApp datatable

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, datatable, reactive

Imported a csv file with some #N/A values, like below.

| Name | Num 1 | Num 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 1 | 2 |
| Ben | #N/A | 1 |
| Chris | 3 | 5 |

Whereas I would like my output like below, with Var being a user input via sidebar; in this case, Var = 2.

| Name | Num 1 | Num 2 | Num1 * Num2 * Var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| Ben | #N/A | 1 | #N/A |
| Chris | 3 | 5 | 30 |

As there are errors, I tried to handle the error (by replacing the #N/As temporarily with 1) in the server chunk of the code, and then replacing them back later. Here is my code (simplified).

```
library(shiny)
library(xts)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("var", "Var",2),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data <- renderTable({
    # VOL 20 error handling
    NA_rows <- which(tabl$Num1 == "#N/A")
    tabl$Num1[NA_rows] <- 1
    
    # Process
    tabl$'Num1 * Num2 * Var' <- tabl$Num1 * tabl$Num2 * input$var 
    tabl$Num1[NA_rows] <- "#N/A"
    tabl$'Num1 * Num2 * Var'[NA_rows] <- "#N/A"
    tabl
  }, bordered=TRUE, digits=5)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, the non-numeric argument to binary operator error keeps popping up regardless of how I handle the #N/As it seems, even though when I do the numeric operations there should be no #N/A values within the datatable... any ideas?

Comment: "Imported a csv file with some #N/A values, like below." Set the proper `na.strings` during import (thereby turning the missing vakues into `NA` values). That will result in the column being numeric after import and you don't need to do any replacements with `1` because `NA` can be numeric.

Comment: Yea that works too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Know someone who can answer?

Yea that's myself 5 minutes later... Crazy how much good a quick Google can do huh?

Turns out the column Num1 are still characters, so even if I changed the #N/As to 1, I still can't multiple Num1 to Num2. Use as.numeric on Num1 to solve.

Comment: This is an inefficient and roundabout way of handling the actual issue. The actual issue can be solved much easier.